# Java - Execute batch file as deamon process

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a .bat file  , when I run this batch from cmd , I only have a way to stop it by ctrl + C or kill process of batch file .

How can I start it as deamon process.
I mean that after I start it from a command prompt window , I can continue to do others commands on this windows with no matter about running batch ?

On Linux we have a command to do similar job  :

`./shellscript.sh > /dev/null >2&1` (I couldn't remember exactly )

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, the proper way to run a daemon is as a service. You can use [procrun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) (part of Apache Commons Daemon) to install your Java program as a Windows service.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to using 3rd party ,I just want run from Java  process

Comment: Apache is not usually considered "third-party"; it's a major part of the Java ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you are marking this Java, but if you are trying to do it from Java, then when you start the Process, it will continue to run in the background until it ends, or you kill it. Note that you need to consume its output for it to not block.

If you're just doing this from batch file, then this [superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background) may answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know. The OP says he wants to continue working in the SAME command window after starting it. He didn't say anything about it being a service or Java program. But concept of daemon is different than background. He says daemon (which your answer is right), but then says "continue to do other commands on this window" which says to me he just wants `start /b` like in my linked superuser post. His Linux example wasn't helpful as it is neither an example of a daemon process start, nor a background process start. His example leaves process in foreground but discards all output.

Comment: Yes . I'm marking this Java because I want run a bat from Java , but the first I want to know the way to do this from cmd prompt

Comment: It's work with start /b . but I apply to java , It's hang . Please help me to check my command . `cmd /c start /b C:\\script_test.bat > nul`

Comment: This is a non-issue if you are running the bat from Java. start /b only makes sense from command prompt. From Java you just run it, it's always run in the background. Just run "cmd /C script_test.bat" from Java. You'll need to start threads to drain the process stdout and stderr or the process will hang when its buffer fill up.

Comment: Thanks, Please see this snipt code [link](http://pastebin.com/yGCZEBRJ), This script can print "test1" and "test2" but thread's script still there, I don't want comsume stdout-stderr, just want to start and leave it running and exit my java code, I've tried with ` > nul ` parameter but have no luck